# Can I Wick-contract terms with derivatives with terms without derivatives?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differentiation, wick-theorem

Consider for example the QCD three point vertex, can I contract a gluon field with the gluon field with a derivative in the vertex?

Comment: If you do it the right way. Relabel all vertices to have unique variables, pull the derivative out of the expectation value, then expand the expectation value using Wick's theorem, then apply the derivatives, then let the new variables converge against the old ones (in an appropriate causal fashion).

Comment: i don't understand your comment. How do I pull out the derivatice out of the expectation value?

Comment: If you work in momentum space, you can contract the field as usual getting the propagator contracted with the 4-momentum

Comment: Taking the expectation value and taking derivatives with respect to free variables commute: $\left< \partial_x a \right> = \partial_x \left< a \right>$.